# I want to take input for while loop by user and i want download the end result

Tags: python, audio, looper

Actually I was writing a program in python to create a audio lopper  I want to take input from user for no of times to loop and  and i want to download the file can any one help me

```
count = 0
while count < 108:
import playsound
import time
playsound.playsound("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SAMPLE\\m1.mp3" )
time.sleep(10)
count = count+1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want the looped music to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `input()` function to take input from the user and then `int()` to typecast it into an integer(default input type is a string).

```
import playsound
import time

user_input = int(input('enter number: '))
count = 0
while count < user_input:
    playsound.playsound("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SAMPLE\\m1.mp3" )
    time.sleep(10)
    count = count+1
```

Comment: can you also help me  such that we can download the looped song pls

Comment: @SANJAYMALLADI What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: i wanted to loop a song and the able to save it for future without using code always